# calendar weekview - set start and end time on the view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

I have a team sharepoint site.

i have created a calendar for the team/group

when looking at the calendar in week view.

i want the day to start at 8 and end at 17.

anyway to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible with OOB calendar. There is no view scope for showing events in Calendar view within a designated range (start at 8 and end at 17). You need to build a custom add-in.

Some knowledge about how to develop in SharePoint Online:

[SharePoint development](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/)

[Plan customizations, solutions, and apps for SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plan-customizations-solutions-and-apps-for-SharePoint-Online-b7898ebf-69b7-4196-81e3-b04e1a4e7d67)